# Is it safe to compost junk mail?

Tags: compost, safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How should I use corrugated cardboard for mulch?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/474/how-should-i-use-corrugated-cardboard-for-mulch)
>   [Cereal boxes for mulch?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/cereal-boxes-for-mulch)
>   [Which inks which can safely be added to vermicompost bins?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/inks-which-can-safely-be-added-to-vermicompost-bins)

I've been shredding and composting my junk mail, to get rid of the damn stuff and also get carbon into the compost.  But recently it occurred to me that the inks could have toxic stuff in them and that this could get into food in the garden.  Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: Somewhat related: [Cereal boxes for mulch?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1060/394) & [How should I use corrugated cardboard for mulch?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/474/394)

Comment: Also related: [Inks which can safely be added to vermicompost bins](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1450/inks-which-can-safely-be-added-to-vermicompost-bins)

Comment: @JoshuaFrank Let me know if the answers there addressed your question and we'll close this as a duplicate of those.

Comment: @LoremIpsum: Actually, none of these really do address the question completely. It sounds like inks on glossy paper might be toxic, but I'm not sure if the inks on regular white paper are okay.